# (idea) Add Gubuntu (pure Gnome 3) to the list of Ubuntu Desktop Version

Tags: gnome

Ubuntu has announced his own 'shell' called unity. I have the idea that Ubuntu adds a new list for it's desktop versions, with Gubuntu, a pure Gnome 3.0 edition of Ubuntu (just like Kubuntu), so the entire list of Ubuntu may be like this:

1. Ubuntu  (unity)
2. Gubuntu (pure Gnome 3.0)
3. Kubuntu
4. Xubuntu
5. Lubuntu
6. Edubuntu
7. Ubuntu Server Edition

Actually, I prefer a version that looks like this:

1. Ubuntu Unity Edition
2. Ubuntu Gnome Edition
3. Ubuntu KDE Edition
4. Ubuntu XFCE Edition
5. Ubuntu LXDE Edition
6. Ubuntu Education Edition
7. Ubuntu Server Edition

so, the name of Ubuntu will be more unified and simple for all versions.
What do you think?

Comment: The best place to place this idea is the [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) website.

People there will be able to vote for this idea and, if popular enough, be included in the next Ubuntu release.

Comment: you do know that you can get rid of unity and use classic gnome right?, why making YEAT ANOTHER ubuntu derivative

Comment: There is such a thing as [too much choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paradox_of_Choice:_Why_More_Is_Less); customers presented with [30 flavors of jam buy less than those presented with 6 flavors](http://www.columbia.edu/~ss957/articles/Choice_is_Demotivating.pdf). From a branding perspective I'd go with just three variants: Ubuntu Desktop, Netbook and Server. Those are terms most people can relate to, while I still don't know the difference between e.g. KDE and Gnome. But agree that this belongs on Ubuntu Brainstorm; it's a discussion rather than a question having an answer.

Comment: @j-g-faustus, with Unity taking over Natty, [Ubuntu Desktop and Netbook are no more](http://blog.canonical.com/?p=528).

Comment: @Oxwivi From my perspective, even better :) Thanks for the link!

Comment: This is not a question...

Comment: YAUD - Yet Another Ubuntu Derivative, that is funny lol